# How to assign a double click as a keyboard shortcut

Tags: interface, shortcut

I've tried searching for this seemingly obvious topic. The following article has been the most accurate and detailed I've found so far for what I'm trying to do (see Benu's reply):

http://blenderartists.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-376596.html

It's from Jul 2015, so not too old. Except it describes a left dropdown list and right dropdown list in the User Preferences, next to individual shortcuts, which I do not have. Nor a "double click" option. I'm just finding my way around Blender, version 2.76b. Best I can do is selecting "Mouse" in the device dropdown list and enter "Right click" (or left) as event. No other fields.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Blender User Preferences > Input > 3D View > Mesh

Add a new keyboard entry with the operator `mesh.loop_select` change input type to *Mouse* and select *Left* > *Double Click*

[image]

Comment: Also one small note of advice, you might want to be careful when assigning Double Click to any operators as you might frequently run into conflicts, like unintentionally spoiling your current selection when quickly selecting edges, of if blender becomes slow or unresponsive it might inadvertently register as a double click.

Comment: Thanks, I completely overlooked that "Loop Select" can also be expanded (with the arrow)! I thought it was the bottom of the hierarchy already.
Also, I'll have an eye out for performance impacts but for now I want to try  making it work more like Modo.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using AHK: https://autohotkey.com/
It provides a scripting language for assigning various hotkeys/shortcuts.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look.